# Can a cabal library include a preprocessor macro?

Tags: haskell, cabal

Cabal automatically exposes preprocessors macros for library version, GHC version, OS etc.

From a library I'm writing I want to expose a macro to users of my library. I didn't find a way online if this is even possible.

Comment: Don't think you can. Perhaps you should say a bit more about why you think you need this; we may be able to suggest alternatives that are close enough that they get you where you need to go.